# How to hardcode actual path to a maven repository in Gradle, Android?

Tags: android, android-gradle-plugin

I have an strange issue. I just pulled our `master` branch and I am the only developer who get following error message among many Android developers in my company.

```
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Could not resolve all files for configuration ':bookingcore-android:debugCompileClasspath'.
> Could not find play-services-ads-identifier.jar (com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads-identifier:15.0.1).
  Searched in the following locations:
      https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/com/google/android/gms/play-services-ads-identifier/15.0.1/play-services-ads-identifier-15.0.1.jar
```

we have following in root `build.gradle` file

```
repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
        ...
}
```

and in one of our modules:

```
plugins {
    id 'com.android.library'
    id 'kotlin-android'
    id 'kotlin-android-extensions'
}
dependencies { 
    ....
    implementation "com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads-identifier:15.0.1"
}
```

Based on my search, actual maven path to `play-services-ads-identifier.jar` is https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.google.android.gms/play-services-ads-identifier/15.0.1. Is there anyway to tell gradle to download `play-services-ads-identifier.jar` from this link rather than google maven?

Comment: have you tried to remove the google repository, sync and then readd the google repo?

Comment: it exists there, but as aar package, not jar. Try to add `@aar` to the end of dependency, does it help?. https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/com/google/android/gms/play-services-ads-identifier/15.0.1/play-services-ads-identifier-15.0.1.pom

Comment: @gmetax, how can I do that?

Comment: remove `google()` do a sync for grandle (ignore the errors) re add `google()` re sync

Comment: Didn't work for me unfortunatly @gmetax. Thanks.

Comment: @nikis, worked. Thanks. Please put your comment as answer and I'll accept it.

Comment: @CommonsWare already gave detailed answer

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Based on my search, actual maven path to play-services-ads-identifier.jar is https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.google.android.gms/play-services-ads-identifier/15.0.1

No, that is a Web page. Among other things, it contains:

> Note: this artifact it located at Google repository (https://maven.google.com/)

On my Android Studio 3.1.4 installation, like your coworkers, I am having no problems with:

```
implementation "com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads-identifier:15.0.1"
```

when I have `google()` listed in `allprojects { repositories {} }` in the root `build.gradle`.

For some reason, your Android Studio seems to think that this is a JAR, when it is really an AAR.

Tactically, you can force the issue, by changing the line to:

```
implementation "com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads-identifier:15.0.1@aar"
```

However, that is treating a symptom, not whatever the underlying problem is.

If you want to try fixing the underlying problem, try these:

1. If you have not done so already, do Build > Clean Project, and see if it picks up the AAR (I doubt that this helps, but it's always a good first step)
2. If that does not help, try File > Invalidate Caches/Restart, and see if it then picks up the AAR
3. You can try to [clear the build cache](https://developer.android.com/studio/build/build-cache#clear_the_build_cache) if you are using Gradle 3.3 or higher, then see if it picks up the AAR
4. If that does not help, you can try closing Android Studio, renaming `~/.gradle/caches` (or the equivalent on Windows) to something else, re-opening Android Studio, and seeing if it then picks up the AAR as it re-downloads all of your dependencies (if this works, you can delete the renamed directory; if it fails, you can always restore the renamed directory)

Comment: Awesome explanation. Thanks for that. I could build successfully on step 3rd.

Comment: Since two days ago I had a lot of errors in IDE (particularly imports) while I was able to build my project successfully via command line. To fix IDE issue, I closed AS, I opened project folder, renamed `.idea` folder and opened my project again. All errors are gone now.